# If term after word in string is a float

Tags: php

I have a string:

```
$string = 'Hello world Vol. 3.5 ispum 99';
```

I want to *get* the float/int value after the term `vol`, so I end up with:

```
$value = '3.5';
```

## What I've tried so far

The only approach I can think of is to `explode(' ', $string)` and check if the iteration after `Vol.` is a float.

Is there a different/better approach?

## Reason why

I pull tons of posts via RSS with random post titles. I aim to determine which volume each post is related to. The term *volume* varies on each post, so we could have: `Vol.`, `volume`, `episode`, `book` etc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use regular expression for this:

```
$string = 'Hello world Vol. 3.5 ispum 99';
if (preg_match('/(Vol\.|volume|episode)\s*(\d+(\.\d+)?)/i', $string, $matches))
    var_dump($matches[2]);
```

- `(Vol\.|volume|episode)` matches any of given words
- `\s*` eats any number of whitespaces
- `(\d+(\.\d+)?)` matches integer or float value

Or more generally:

```
$terms = ['vol.', 'volume', 'episode'];
$terms_quoted = [];
foreach ($terms as $term)
    $terms_quoted[] = preg_quote($term, '/');

$string = 'Hello world Vol. 3.5 ispum 99';
if (preg_match('/('.implode('|', $terms_quoted).')\s*(\d+(\.\d+)?)/i', $string, $matches))
    var_dump($matches[2]);
```

Comment: What's the case-insensitive approach with regex again?

Comment: @HenrikPetterson You mean the `i` modifier? `preg_match('/.../i', ...)`.

Comment: Yes, can you please add the `i` modifier. Also, it doesn't match with `$string = '99 Hello world Vol.2.3';` -- note the lack of spacing between `Vol.` and the float.

Comment: **VERY** nice. You have a typo with `$temrs` but totally works well.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe not really pretty, but this works:

```
$string = 'Hello world Vol. 3.5 ispum';
echo (float) trim(preg_replace("/[^0-9\.]/","", $string), ".");
```

First remove all characters using the `preg_replace` except for numbers and dots. Then remove all dots at the beginning of end of the string using `trim()`.

Comment: Interesting. But it breaks if the string is something like `$string = 'Hello 99 world Vol. 3.5 ispum';`

Comment: Is there a pattern in all those titels you can use? Does it always contain the word 'vol.' for example? If not it will be a really difficult task to get it right, it requires machine learning. A simpler solution might be to leave the spaces intact as well and reside to your original solution by exploding it on spaces. At least you know you will only have numbers left. Then you might check the value of the numbers. Volume 3.5 is a better guess then volume 99.

Answer (score 1):

`filter_var` works in this condition as well and it is used to filter a variable with some specified filter conditions.  To read more about [filter_var()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.filter-var.php)

The `FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_FLOAT` filter is used to remove all illegal characters from a float number and `FILTER_FLAG_ALLOW_FRACTION` is allowing fraction separator something like `" . "`

```
$string = 'Hello world Vol. 3.5 ispum';

echo trim(filter_var($string, FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_FLOAT, FILTER_FLAG_ALLOW_FRACTION), '.');
```

First of all, `filter_var` is filtering the string and removing all characters from the string except digits and dots. So from the given string the result should look like this **`.3.5`**, so if you add trim on the filtered string then output should look like this **`3.5`**

Comment: This is a really interesting one, but doesn't work with `$string = '99 Hello world Vol. 3.5 ispum';` or similar scenarios.

Answer (score 1):

You can trim the string so that it starts with a number
then PHP can correctly convert it

```
$str = 'Hello world Vol. 3.5 ispum'; 
$pos = strpos($str, 'Vol.') + 4; 
$val = (float)substr($str, $pos); 
var_dump($val);
```

float(3.5)

see docs to get more details [String conversion to numbers](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.conversion)

Comment: Please add some explanation.

Answer (score 0):

May this will help you

```
$string = 'Hello world Vol. 4.5 ispum 99';
$arry = explode(' ',$string);
$key = array_search('Vol.',$arry)+1; //you can use volume,book etc
$value = floatval($arry[$key]);
if($value && intval($value) != $value)
{
    echo $value." is a float";
}
else
{
    echo $value." is not a float";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$title = 'Hello world episode 342 ispum 99';
// Works also for
// $title = 'Hello world Vol. 3.5 ispum 99';
// $title = 'Hello world volume 23.53 ispum 2345';
// $title = 'Hello world book 34532 ispum 4';
$matches = array();
// Check if there is any volume data in our title
foreach(['Vol.', 'volume', 'episode', 'book'] as $term){
    if (strpos($title, $term) !== false) {
        // Bingo! Now take the first int/float after the found term
        preg_match("/(\d+(\.\d+)?)/", explode($term, $title)[1], $matches);
        print_r($matches[0]);
        return;
    }
}
```